# SignalR Client How to Set user when start connection?

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Server side:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
    var user = Context.User.Identity.Name; // Context.User is NULL
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

Client side (in Console project):

```
IHubProxy _hub;
string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
var connection = new HubConnection(url);
_hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");
connection.Start().Wait();
```

When the client connect to the server, I want to know the map between userName and connectionId, But `Context.User` is NULL.  How do I set this value in the client side?

Comment: What kind of authentication do you use? If you use ASP.NET built in authentication it should just work

Comment: I didn't use any kind of authentication ...  I just build a new empty project and download signalr from NuGet

Comment: Well you need to have Authentication enabled and then Context.User will just work

Comment: Since you use .NET client you also need to set the credentails on the client hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials (This code applies to Windows authentication)

Comment: In case you are using the **Azure SignalR Service** see [How to use SignalR to send data to a specific user?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58996650/7910454)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pass your username using query string.

**Client**

First set query string

```
string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
var connection = new HubConnection(url);
_hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");
connection.qs = { 'username' : 'anik' };
connection.Start().Wait();
```

**Server**

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    var username= Context.QueryString['username'];
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

Comment: I have [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58630559/7910454) and would appreciate any help a lot

Comment: 'HubConnection' does not contain a definition for 'qs' and no accessible extension method 'qs' accepting a first argument of type 'HubConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @HOÀNGLONG old ASP.NET SignalR or new ASP.NET Core SignalR?

Answer (score 21):

try this with queryString in **asp.netcore 2.1**:

**Client (javascript)**
set query string after url like follow:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:10499/chathub?username=xxxx").build();
connection.start().then(function ()
{
    // do some thing here ...
}).catch(function (err)
{
    console.error(err.toString());
});
.
.
.
```

**Server**

```
public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var  username = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["username"];
        // username = xxxx
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I have [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58630559/7910454) and would appreciate any help a lot

Comment: This is the most acceptable one according to me. I tried all the others but to no avail. This required a double +

Answer (score 2):

**Client**

```
var connection = new HubConnection(<YOUR_URL>);
connection.Headers.Add("username", "maria");
var myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
```

---

**Server**

```
string username = Context.Headers.Get("username");
Console.WriteLine("New client connection - " + username);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is required that you mention and explain the changes and why you changed them. This will help the OP to learn and know why the changes were made and where

Answer (score 0):

If your using basic authentication create a new **System.Net.NetworkCredential**

```
string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
var connection = new HubConnection(url);

NetworkCredential myCredentials = new NetworkCredential("","","");
myCredentials.Domain = "domain";
myCredentials.UserName = "username";
myCredentials.Password = "passwd";   

connection.Credentials = myCredentials;

_hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");


connection.Start().Wait();
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential.username?view=net-6.0

Answer (score -1):

try this

**Client (C#)**

```
       //Enter query string 
       var querystringData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
       querystringData.Add("username", "naveed");


       IHubProxy _hub;
       string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
       var connection = new HubConnection(url);
       _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");
       connection.Start().Wait();
       connection.Start().Wait();
```

**Server**

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
  var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
  var username= Context.QueryString["username"]; //here you will receive naveed as username

  return base.OnConnected();
}
```