# How to create Azure Functions output binding for SignalR to add a **connection** to a group?

Tags: javascript, azure, signalr, azure-functions

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-3.1#groups-in-signalr), in SignalR, "A group is a collection of **connections** associated with a name." A little further up that page, it also says that **users** can have multiple **connections** (one from your phone and another from your desktop for example).

But in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-output?tabs=javascript#group-management) of an Azure Function output binding for SignalR group management, it appears that you are adding a **user** to a group not a connection.

According to the accepted answer for [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630559/how-to-use-signalr-to-send-data-to-a-specific-user), it appears that connectionInfo can be captured as the third parameter in the Azure Function signature, but it's unclear to me how you'd put that in the output binding example above.

So, how do you create an Azure Functions output binding for SignalR to add a **connection** to a group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement "A group is a collection of connections associated with a name." is from [asp.net core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1) documentation, not from the [PaaS offering of managed SignalR service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-signalr/). In asp.net core one, you have the low level control of adding connection to group. But in the managed service (which is what is supported in function), it abstracts it to the user level where you can add/remove **user** to a group. For practical purposes, the group management for the user makes more sense than trying to manage low level connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is disappointing. I was going to try to create a group per component on my page and use it to update just that part of the page. With this answer, I'll have to multiplex and keep track of separately.

Also, the fact that there are differences in the implementations and it's not clear what documentation goes with which implementation is no fun.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will pass it to the relevant team.